# What makes the tonic the tonic and when do I know it changed?

Tags: theory, scales, harmony

What makes a note the tonal center of a scale other than forcing the listener to come from and go back to the selected note as the center? Or is that what makes that note the tonal center?

Also at what point can you say for sure that the tonal center has changed?
I understand there are probably plenty of gray areas, but this is me trying to get a better grip on this concept.

Comment: Are you asking about a particular style, like either classical or pop?

Answer (score 9):

Let me take a controversial stance: the tonic is **always** subjective.

There is no such thing as one *objective* tonic at any particular point in a compostition. I'm not arguing that the idea of a tonic is useless, though, I'm just saying that *the best conceptual understanding of a tonic* (or tonal center, or key center, or a bunch of other phrases that refer to the same central measure of a piece) *must recognise that this center is based on perception and is subjective and personal.*

A tonal center is like a reference point in physics: yes, you could calculate the motion of that baseball with respect to the wave going around the bleachers, but you'll find it much more useful to analyse the motion of that baseball relative to home plate. In the same vein, **a key is a perspective from which analysis can be constructed.** Take "Fly Me to the Moon", for example. You could say that the key is C major, or you could say that the key is A minor. Both of these lenses allow one to easily observe patterns present in the song and interpret them. However, it is also possible to analyse the song as being in the B Locrian mode, though of course it is not useful to analyse the song from that point of view. You could even analyse it from the perspective of D major, where of course the first note wouldn't be in the diatonic key and the first chord would be v. Obviously, any theorist worth their salt would throw that conclusion out the window immediately, but that's what **good analysis requires: isolating the useful frameworks of C major and A minor, and discarding useless approaches like B Locrian and D major.**

It might not even be useful to give a piece a single label with respect to a key: the key can change, as anyone who's learned about modulation knows. A piece can even have multiple "valid" interpretations: I know I've written music before where I meant for it to sound like it was in one key, but listeners identified a different key as the tonal center. The classic example of this is when someone wants to write some music in the Locrian mode as a theory exercise, but it ends up sounding like Phrygian or one of the other modes. Plus, music doesn't have to be diatonic; composers have been blurring the lines with regard to the key of a piece for centuries: modal interchange, secondary dominants, chromatic planing, and plenty of other techniques to get off of the white keys and play with the listener's perception of the key. And once you get to polytonalism and twelve-tone serialism, any opposition to my point really starts to fall flat on its face.

This is not just a theoretical semantics debate: there are numerous well-known examples of music that has seen analyses with varying tonics. For some well-known extreme examples, "Giant Steps" - not just one "objective tonic" (not even close). "4:33" - I'd love to hear your opinions on the tonic of that piece. Even "Sweet Home Alabama" has been making the rounds in the media as an ambiguous case.

---

> *"So if the tonic is always subjective, then how am I supposed to analyze music?"*

, you ask. Well, **the tonic is what you personally hear as the note around which everything falls into place, usually best determined by the melody.** One good way to check is to see what notes are in the song and then see what key would have those diatonic pitches. Be very careful doing this, though - this method quickly falls apart with music that gets out of diatonic harmony (which probably happens more often than you'd expect). If you hear a change in that basic set of notes at some point in the song, that's a clue that the song may have changed its tonal center. It's also often useful to study cadences and their patterns of resolution, but again, this can be and is often subverted. Ultimately, trust in your own ears first, then check to see whether other clues confirm this hypothesis. Experienced musicians will do this process in their head from multiple angles at once ("hmm, the notes are blah blah and blah, the melody sounds to me like blah, and this makes blah blah type of cadence - pretty clearly in F♯ minor!").

> *"I think I'm doing this right, but sometimes I get the key 'wrong'. How do I know I'm using the right process to figure out the key?"*

If you can do this process correctly, you should have no trouble **analyzing the blues**. Often, a struggle to determine the key of a blues song is an indicator that someone is using the wrong methods to arrive at their analysis of the key of a piece.

> *"Wait a minute, how can there be a 'wrong' way to figure out the key? Didn't you just spend a whole paragraph explaining that the key is subjective?"*

Okay, technically there's no such thing as the wrong method, in the same way that analysis can't really be "wrong" either. But that doesn't mean that there can't be flawed logic involved. When people talk about "the wrong key", that's a shorthand for the implicit understanding that the key identified by that analysis is useless in terms of understanding the music. In the same way, the "wrong" way to analyze the key of a piece is "wrong" because it often leads to useless ("invalid") conclusions, and is not very efficient for arriving at useful analyses.

---

If you want to get better at doing this identification, the best and fastest way to improve is to listen to a lot of music (like, a LOT - this comes with experience) and just take a second to try and determine the key. If you can, get another musician to verify what they hear as the tonic - the internet can and often does lead to counterproductive interpretations, because computers are bad at subjective tasks like this one. Plus, the humans posting on the internet are not all experts (hopefully, you trust that I know what I'm talking about, but there are plenty of people willing to post stuff online that don't have a solid grasp on what they're talking about).

Occasionally, you may stumble upon a piece that you just can't seem to wrap your head around - even if you're a seasoned veteran theorist. Those are the cases where it can be best to reject the idea of a key entirely, or use two keys to explain the patterns you hear, or identify a change in the key, and just accept that it's possible to interpret something multiple ways, and that there isn't always just one correct answer.

---

One final (hopefully) addendum, just as a nod to some other sentiments that I may have initially done a poor job of explaining:

**My answer above is more of an advanced conceptual-level approach to harmonic understanding.** It works very well for the intermediate-to-expert theorist, but it can be a bit involved for a novice.

Ultimately, your goal in developing the skill of identifying the tonic should be to be so quick and accurate that for most songs it will *feel objective*. [User Albrecht Hügli's answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/96379/37992) is a great starting point towards developing this skill from a novice standpoint. You should be able to say to yourself most of the time, "Yep, the song's obviously in D minor" without a doubt in your mind. You of course would know conceptually that it's a shorthand for knowing that D minor is by far the most convenient choice of a key for conventional harmonic analysis. When you practice, especially as a beginner, there should most of the time be one best answer - if there's more than one, you're picking the wrong examples to practice with.

### **To sum it all up:**

*Learn to figure out the key of simpler (one clear best key) musical examples efficiently. Once you have that skill in the bag, then in order to tackle more advanced harmony, you must grasp that a tonal center is a perspective from which anaysis makes sense, and learn to trust your ear.*

Comment: Great! :D About feeling the tonal center: IMO you can't really learn that by listening only, you have to _interact_ with the music. Practice by accompanying melodies with different chords by ear. I can, at will, imagine in my mind without actually playing, major or minor-key i.e. tonal center perspectives to "Fly me to the moon" and that skill comes from accompanying by ear. Melody starting from C, chords e.g. C - F - G  - C ... _or_ Am - Dm - Em - Am - ... It's _subjective_, and every listener forms a _perspective_. Which can of course be strongly _suggested_ and guided with an arrangement!

Comment: Had to laugh at '4:33'. The big problem there was that the orchestra didn't even tune up before it, so it is doubly difficult to define its tonic. Another chestnut is 'Unforgettable'.

Comment: Your description of what "experienced musicians" do is spot on! It's more about trying to guess the composer's intent, than directly identify "the key"...

Comment: Analysis can totally have wrong answers and in cases where ambiguity exits, there's not more than 2 tonal centers identified. As I stated in topo's answer and will continue to state a key and tonic have objective criteria that allows analysis to happen. Not all music is tonal so trying to apply it every time won't work, but it's also like trying to fix every problem with just a hammer.

Comment: @Dom It seems to me that your statement "trying to apply it every time won't work" isn't a million miles away from the position of this answer, and my answer. Beyond that, it seems that you're insisting that the question here (and answers thereto) should concern only *tonal* music, and furthermore, that it should do so according to a *definition* of tonal that allows objective analysis of tonal centre. The question doesn't say that, but you may nevertheless be reading the OP right - so why not put your objective criteria for finding the tonal center(s) of tonal music into an answer?

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica I wasn't talking about your answer with that quote just how some songs not having a key doesn't take away from it being a useful analysis tool and there are several answers that state objective methods to find the tonic so I don't want to add noise to the already given good answers. If you mention a tonic, you are talking about tonal music. If we can't agree on that, we really can't have a conversation about key because that is the assumption we need to make which goes back to the tool analogy. If the music is not tonal then talking about key and tonic don't make sense.

Comment: For example, "4:33"  is not tonal nor is a lot of his music like his "radio music". It's not ambiguous, it won't work because isn't not tonal.

Comment: On the subjectivity of the tonic: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17225/finding-the-shadaj-tonic-in-hindustani-sangeet-north-indian-classical-music

Comment: @Dom I guess the OP will have to get back to us on whether his use of the word 'tonic' implied that the question should only relate to certain types of music. I'm used to people (even here) using the term more casually. Do you agree that not all music with a 'home note' satisfies every other criterion in every other definition of 'tonal'?

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica we're getting away from the question. If you're a student in a music theory 101 class, this question is in the lesson plan at least the very basics. We're muddying information by not addressing the direct question and saying it's subjective when especially from an analysis point of view it's anything but that. Both identifying a tonic and when the tonic/key changes are big parts of intro music theory.  If you want to start to talk about post tonal composition and analysis I'm all for that, but we need to answer the basics first.

Comment: @Dom what "the basics" are isn't always clear in many subjects, and certainly not in music. You don't have to be thinking in terms of post-tonal analysis to try on the idea that what the tonic is, ultimately, is a *feeling*. One student might well see that as muddying the waters; another might see it as *the* fundamental point around which to build all other knowledge on the subject; yet another might see it as something to bear in mind whilst still being perfectly happy to start with conventional analysis techniques.

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica and in theory terms it's stability not feeling. It's the place where you resolve to which again gets back to basics of what resolution means in tonal harmony which comes down to the tonic-dominant relationship and cadences. Again back to the music theory 101 class if you try to justify a tonic with "feeling" rather than the objective analysis then it's not going to work. The basics in music theory are very analytical not  subjective for a reason which is to lay the foundation and finding a key/tonic is part of that.

Comment: @Dom the 'stability' isn't *literal* - nothing's going to actually crash onto the floor if we don't resolve quickly enough. It's a *feeling* of stability. Like many feelings, it has psychological and cultural foundations that mean that many people may share the same subjective feelings (or feel that they do), and even come up with a common language to describe those (apparently) shared feelings. To me, that's still squarely in the land of subjectivity, but that's just a question of how the word 'subjective' is defined... yet another thing about which people may well disagree, I guess!

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica it's not stable to you or stable to me. It's stable as defined by the Tonal harmony which again is objective because there are defined relationships for determining stability. It works well for a good chunk of western music even as it's typical mixed a little with other cultures, not necessarily for other cultures or historic cultures. For example, in counterpoint in  fux, 4ths are dissonant in some contexts, but they may not sound it to you or me. It's a well defined system you may or may not agree with.

Comment: @Dom I kind of circled back a bit in the new last bit of my answer, trying to explain how this brave new world of subjective keys relates to the more fundamental concepts taught in music school. Hopefully that conveys the limitations of my answer a little better than before.

Answer (score 6):

1. There are some rare tunes that are only built on notes of the triad of the tonic like a canon:

1111 333- 5555 888- 5588 558- 5533 551- Here we have an absolut clear situation: No cadence but only tonic ... or this fantastic march of the Swiss Army ;)

2. There are many songs just commuting between tonic and dominant:

"Hey ho, Skip to my Lou", "Frère Jacques", "Sur le pont d'Avignon", and many other folk melodies  and baby songs: The final chord is always the tonic, and the song begins almost always with the tonic.

3. The most important factor of the tonic  is the appearance of a cadence:

V-I is an authentic cadence, but if we have only 2 chords without context we don't know whether this is V/V or I-IV  (=V/IV).
In minor V-i could also be the dominant of any other minor degree. So -  as long   we don't know whether we have an perfect authentic cadence or an imperfect  cadence the tonic is not defined.

As soon we have the 3 functions I-IV-V-I (or I ii V7 I) we have a tonal center: this can be in any place of 3 neighbor chords in the circle of fifths: If 3 neighbor keys (degrees) are "cadencing" that the progression ends on the middle key of the 3  degrees we have a perfect authentic cadence and a new tonic center.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence#Imperfect_authentic_cadence

Comment: If there are only two chords in a song, and one includes the b7, making it a dominant seventh chord, would that point to the tonic better? Agree about the cadence, it's probably the most telling factor.

Comment: I know what you mean! I've edited point 3 => 3a and 3b. The context will decide it: In such songs we have normally the final chord that defines the tonic.

Comment: @Tim Agreed. But what about if there are three chords and they all include the b7? I'm looking at you, 12 bar blues. No-one would say that the tonic of a blues in C is Bb!

Comment: @AdamChalcraft - good point, and my idea would be to take all three chords and check them with the circle of 4/5s. The central one will be the key/tonic. Blues is/are notorious for breaking the 'rules'.

Comment: I'll give this a +1 for covering the basic levels of harmony with a clear method, which is something I kind of neglected in my answer.

Comment: "There are some rare tunes that are only built on notes of the triad of the tonic like a canon": such tunes are not rare, however, in bugle literature.

Comment: @phoog: Yes, we have to consider then all tones that might be based on the dominant as passing tones. E.g. *amazing grace*  can be accompanied with the tonic.

Answer (score 5):

The way to figure out what the tonic is, is to see around which note the melody revolves and resolves.

If you have a song that is in C major, the melody will most likely be based around the note *C*. Take note though, that the melody will emphasize the note *C*. That means it will be played in cadences, in strong beats etc, if the composer wants to give you the feeling that it *is the tonic*.

Also, since we are talking about *Tonal Music*, you can take a look at the [leading tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading-tone). In this kind of music, the leading tone will lead (most of the times) to the tonic. So let's take once again the C major example. In this scale the leading tone is *B* and it will lead to *C*.

There are many ways to see if/when/how the tonic has changed, but the simplest way would be to see if the above statements have changed. E.g. if the tonic has changed to A major, you would find that the melody revolves around the note *A*, the leading tone would be *G#* and it'd lead to *A*.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica sometimes yes, other times no. It depends on what kind of song it is. Bach in his chorales used to have multiple parallel lines, but still, you could figure out the tonic center by using (some) of the aforementioned points. The same goes for ambient orchestral backgrounds. Basically, this is one of the things you are being taught in harmony lessons

Comment: Keep in mind that it is highly likely for the composer to deliberately omit a tonic

Comment: Not at all sure I agree with the first two statements. A melody doesn't *necessarily* be based around or emphasise the tonic note. I need to do some homework on that, but it doesn't seem to reflect reality in at least some of the stuff I play. That may be genre - based. True, a lot of the time, the final note *is* the tonic, but that's not set in stone.

Comment: @Tim I agree, that is why i said "If you have a song that is in C major, *the melody will most likely* be based around the note C"

Comment: All this reminds me of 'Sweet Home Alabama'. Some bands I've played it with are adamant it's in key G, while others are equally adamant that it's in key D. Rather a difference...

Comment: I have to downvote this, that's what the plus and minus buttons are for. "The way to figure out what the tonic is, is to see around which note the melody revolves and resolves." That must be, if you're unable to actually _listen_ to the music even in your mind to imagine what it would sound like, then that's the way. But what could possibly be a real-world situation where someone actually has to do figure out the tonal center by _looking_? Is that a very _common_ situation? I would definitely not suggest this as the first option to try or learn. Hearing is a much more elementary skill.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica probably you've never heard of "analyzing scores" :)

Comment: OP seems to be talking about a listener, not a calculator. If you can't sense the "tonicness" of a note, analysis can give a guess, but you validate it by hearing. Sometimes it feels like theory is taken like "music for deaf people", when it should be a tool for reasoning about feelings. Taking deaf/numb as an accepted starting point is like giving up before even getting started. Teaching tricks like "look at the last note" as the first tool (which I've witnessed) ... not good. Tonic is all about feeling. If it doesn't feel like a tonic, it's not the tonic. If you can't feel, learn to?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica since OP hasn't specified whether he is talking about *listening* to music or *analyzing* a score, so you cannot be sure; for me (and many others), it's equally important to be able to analyze a score if you don't have a recording. It's okay if you cannot do that, but it's not wrong, it's something theory students are taught. I don't know who you refer to as a calculator, but putting that aside, I don't understand why you assume I can't *feel the tonic* and I need to *learn to*.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica also, a "a real-world situation where someone actually has to do figure out the tonal center by looking?" would be when someone is composing on paper (something people actually do) and they have someone else look at it, before recording or playing it

Comment: Also, theory/harmony exams. Maybe you haven't taken any, but there are tests where you are given a melody in a piece of paper and you have to harmonize it, without listening to a recording or playing it. You have to work it out just by *looking* at it

Comment: @piiperi-reinstate-monica *But what could possibly be a real-world situation where someone actually has to do figure out the tonal center by looking?* -- session musicians.

Comment: @WillCrawford Aren't those musicians capable of _feeling_ the tonic too, or perhaps they even hear things in their mind when sight-reading? IMO, if you can hear it, you can operate musically and figuring out by sight will be easy to learn too. But if you can't hear something as fundamental as "does this note feel like tonic", then you're lost and analysis won't save you. Hearing is primary and essential. Everything else is there just to assist. Btw, it's perfectly ok to say that any note doesn't feel very strongly like a tonic, because there are ambiguous situations like that.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I meant before you start playing :) otherwise, yes, *playing by ear* is a tautology in a way.

Comment: +1 for the mention of the leading tone.  I'd also add the the leading tone BY ITSELF isn't always enough, but rather the combination of the leading tone AND the 4th scale degree are so strong that you almost can't hear both those notes without elevating the tonic note to a higher position of "this is home."  This is why hearing a IV-V progression is so common in itntroductions.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to tell if the tonic has changed is to see if what Schoenberg calls "neutralization" over an extended period of time. Neutralization occurs when a chromatic form of a note is used instead of the original version. For example, in effecting a move from C major to G major, the F# should emphasized to show that we're no longer in C. One method is to play the V or V7 or the new key, (a D major or D seventh chord in G).

One can used chromatic chords (through the use of secondary dominants for example) for a short period of time (called tonicization) without changing key if a return to the original key happens quickly.

Comment: So, F# is played... how do you know the tonal center is G and not C like in C lydian?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - possibly because there are thousands of times more tunes in Ionian than in Lydian?

Comment: @Tim I just can't see how this answers the OP's question. "There's an F# ... maybe the key changed to G", that's just a guess, but how do you _know_ what is right? How does this answer show how to validate the list of guessed tonal centers?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - I see what you're saying. Possibly that F# needs to move straight to G - several times - would be 'proof' that we're in key G?

Comment: The point is to make the F# sound "native." One suggestion (Schoenberg?) is to use a V7/V, V7, I cadential pattern. Older books (1800s  and some modern ones) call "tonicization" a "short modulation." To some extent, it's a matter of time. Some analysts (Schenker?) sometimes describe sonata exposition as being in a single key with an excursion. Labels are less important than noticing that short chromatic uses sound different from key changes and there's an intermediate region; composers use any one that sounds good to them at the time.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing objective that makes the tonic the tonic. It's a question of judgment and perception, rather than well-defined rules. It's certainly possible to point to conventions within certain styles of music, but nothing definitive.

Sometimes, two people will disagree on what the tonic is. Sometimes it might not be clear that there's an established tonic at all.

The tonic is the tonic for you if you feel it is, and it's changed for you if you feel it's changed. Yes, that may not be true for the next person, but that's the nature of subjective things.

(Please also see [user45266's excellent answer!](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/96399/18896))

Comment: I think this is the only real answer - you _feel_ the tonic, you don't calculate it. If you have to calculate with logical rules, you're lost and disoriented like a pilot who doesn't know which way is up. So many things contribute to the perception of tonic, like rhythmic placement of notes and chord changes in relation to a perceived beat. How many seconds does the feeling of tonic stay, how many seconds does it take to settle down somewhere - it's a very fuzzy and "analog" phenomenon. Not digital rule-based deduction.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - that's fair enough, but would one think that the composer already had a tonic in his mind's ear while writing? Maybe in order to put a key sig.

Comment: @Tim ...but then of course a key sig doesn't define a tonic - and tonics can change even when key sigs don't. And not all compositional processes require having a tonic in mind (though I wouldn't dispute that there are many cases where a) they do, and b) people would be able to follow the composer's thoughts)

Comment: 99.9% of the time in tonal music there is an objective tonic. This is very basic music theory 101 ideas and yes there are times when things can be looked at other ways, but there are reasons and explanations for that are perception and even then the most you'll ever have is 2. Just because you can look at something one way or another does not mean it's not defined or not objective.

Comment: @Dom "99.9% of the time in tonal music there is an objective tonic" - or maybe even 100%, depending on your definition of "tonal"! The question doesn't give a definition, or even specify that it's about "tonal" music for that matter. "Just because you can look at something one way or another does not mean it's not defined or not objective" - well, clearly it does mean that there is no *one* objective way of looking at it. If we agree there, we agree.

Comment: This is a thing you can learn in a Music theory 101 class. Saying " no one objective way of looking at it" implies that you can't  objectively do it especially when you don't offer an objective way to do it. As a site that's about learning about music practice and theory, this doesn't seem to be a constructive answer. Yes you won't find a tonic in certain pieces of music, but we can give the OP a better answer than "There's nothing objective that makes the tonic the tonic" because using theory there is an objective definition which seems to be what the OP is after.

Comment: If there is a tonic, it's tonal.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis there's some where you can look at it multiple ways so there could be two valid tonics, but they do tend to have more of a non functional use of harmony.

Comment: Like polytonality? The OP asked "_the_ tonic".

Comment: @MichaelCurtis like modern songs without strong functional harmony, Tim likes to use Sweet Home Alabama as an example.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis "If there is a tonic, it's tonal" - certainly a simple enough definition, but not the only one I've heard. Many people would regard modal music as not 'tonal', for example, and yet there's usually a clear home note, which many would still call the 'tonic'.

Comment: @Dom "we can give the OP a better answer than *There's nothing objective that makes the tonic the tonic*" - certainly this answer doesn't state *everything* that can be said about the subject; it contains something important that does need to be understood, which in my honest assessment *may* be the thing that the OP needed to know. To disagree with my answer is one thing, but to say "this doesn't seem to be a constructive answer" is disappointing behavior IMO.

Comment: @Dom what are you saying - that if you are so harmony-insensitive that you can't tell if a note feels like a tonic, and can't do any probing with notes and chords either to clarify the feelings, then you can resort to _rules_ you learned from theory classes? You still can't feel it, but at least you have calculated an answer based on rules? Somehow there's something wrong with this picture. :) It's like not sensing if your food is too hot, and then applying knowledge from physics and biology classes to figure out if your tongue is getting burnt.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Analysis can be done without listening, though if you are well studied you can hear it while you analyze via ear training. There are tonal ideas that point to a tonic such as cadences and V-I movement which are vital to tonal definitions and what we subconsciously listen for when being exposed to a lot of tonal music. All of these are tonal constructs which have studied and known results. There are cultures that do not have an ear for tonal music as you or I know it, but it doesn't mean the construct is meaningless or not objective.

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica I'm not trying to be discouraging, but I don't see this as an answer to the question. The other answers are giving the OP direction to figuring it out, this answer just comments on how perception can be different which is true, but doesn't get the OP closer to their answer which the others do.

Comment: Ah, that. Yes, lots of pop songs eschew a tonic so they can keep repeating a groove. Personally, I'm OK with saying something doesn't have a tonic in that style.

Comment: @Dom It's always good when there are different answers from different perspectives! I've not attempted to deny any of the information in the other answers, *unless* anyone were to write "here's a foolproof definition that will always identify the tonic in any piece of music".

Comment: Aww, thanks for the shoutout. Hey @Dom, you seem to have a strong opinion, or at least one that runs counter to a couple of the answers here. Some of us would love it if you could write an answer fleshing out your views on the question, because it's kind of hard to decipher as written in the various comment threads. Plus, I for one would be interested in seeing a diversity of opinions here in the answers - I don't see any other answers taking your position, from what I gather.

Comment: @user45266 the other answers go over points I would post and I don't want to delude the current answer. For example Albrecht Hügli is the basic path I would take and most things I would write would echo that. I'm vocal in the two answers that say tonic is subjective because it's distinctively something people in music theory classes are trained to recognize objectively given tonal music. It's the basis of analysis and it's a fundamental area of music theory so trying to say it's always subjective can be counterproductive to people learning this subject because they aren't learning the basics.

Answer (score 2):

> ...other than forcing the listener to come from and go back to the selected note as the center?

I take that to mean devices like repeating a certain tone or rhythmic things like putting a tone on a strong beat or ending of phrases.

That pretty much leaves *harmony* as the means of defining the tonic.

In the major/minor system cadential harmony defines the tonic. That seems to be the most straight forward way to put it, but of course you then need to understand cadences. A lot of that can be reduced to simply identifying the *dominant* chord and then by extension you will know what the tonic is.

There is only *one* diatonic dominant seventh chord in a key (in minor that chord uses a raised seventh degree.) If the dominant chord is only a triad or otherwise incomplete, you need some other degrees used in the surrounding harmony to complete the tonal picture.

If you can group three tones so that they are separated by fourths, and there is an additional degree a half step below the middle tone of the three, then you have identified the essential tones. The three degrees separated by fourths are the *tonal* degrees, the tonic is the middle one, and the tone one half step below it is the *leading tone*.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to *understand* cadences, non-musos can often pinpoint where cadences occur, and thus find what they think is a tonic, just by how the trend of the music moves to a conclusion. It's not exclusive to learned musicians.

Comment: Sure, their ears can hear the tonic/cadence, but then the question becomes: why? how? So then you explain the theory.